# Finding smallest key value in btreemap, when the key is a tuple

Tags: rust

I have a btreemap like this:

```
use alloc::collections::BTreeMap;
let mut map: BTreeMap<(u16,u16), [u8;32]> = BTreeMap::new();
```

and just for the sake of example, I add these elements:

```
map.insert((1,3), [0;32]);
map.insert((5,3), [1;32]);
map.insert((7,3), [2;32]);
map.insert((2,3), [3;32]);
map.insert((10,3), [4;32]);
```

Now, the keys here are tuples. What I need to do, is to find the smallest key value. But based on the first element of the key tuple.

A totally naive solution would be:

```
let mut n = 5000;
for pair in map.keys(){
    if pair.0 < n{
        n = pair.0;
    }
}
println!("n {}", n);
```

But is there a nicer way of doing this same thing? Maybe more efficient?

Comment: BTreeMaps are ordered, wouldn't the smallest key value just be `map.keys().next().map(|v| v.0)`?

Comment: yeah, but arent they ordered by hash?

Comment: If you were using a HashMap, yes. BTreeMap doesn't use hashing, it only requires that keys have an order, and it maintains the tree in key-sorted order. The documentation for the `keys()` method even states _"Gets an iterator over the keys of the map, in sorted order."_

Comment: ah yeah. this works, thx!

Comment: Cool, I will post an answer with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTreeMaps are already sorted by key, and tuples implement ordering traits when all of their component types do.  Tuples are ordered by their first element, then their second, and so on.  Therefore, you can just grab the first key in the map:

```
let smallest = map.keys().next().map(|v| v.0);
```

This will give you an `Option<u16>` containing the first tuple field of the first (and therefore smallest) key in the map, or `None` if the map is empty.